# What happens when a caster's soul returns to his polymorphed body by the effect of Magic Jar?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, polymorph

Consider the following sequence of actions:

- A caster casts [Magic Jar](https://roll20.net/compendium/dnd5e/Magic%20Jar#content) and his souls travel to the chosen container
- The caster manages to possess an NPS's body. The caster's class features are retained in the new body, together with the original WIS, INT and CHA scores.
- The caster in the new body casts [True Polymorph](https://roll20.net/compendium/dnd5e/True%20Polymorph#content) on the original body and transforms it into a dragon (for example)
- The caster makes is soul travel back to the original, polymorphed body.

Now, what happens to the caster's class features? Are they retained? Is there any difference between this course of actions and simply casting True Polymorph on self?

Answer (score 6):

## The caster is now only under the effect of *true polymorph* as *magic jar* has ended.

### return to the caster's original body ends *magic jar*.

The original body of the caster of magic jar is *true polymorhped* while their soul is not in it due to *magic jar*.  Their soul subsequently returns to their body ending *magic jar* or when *magic jar* ends.

> ...returning to your living body (and ending the spell)...

In either event, *magic jar* is no longer a consideration as it has ended.

### The result is the same as the caster using True Polymorph on themself

The added hassle of the effects of *magic jar* are irrelevant as *magic jar* ends when the caster returns to their original body.

### Could allow a caster to turn themselves into an object.

Normally, a caster can't do this to themselves as they can't maintain concentration after they've turned into a tea cup.

If the caster's original body was transformed into an object until dispelled via *true polymorph*, when *magic jar* ends, they'll either return to it and be trapped until *true polymorph* is dispelled or the caster dies.

> If your body is more than 100 feet away from you or if your body is dead when you attempt to return to it, you die.

This depends on interpreting an object as your body, which is fair considering the edge cases *true polymorph* brings with it anyway.

Comment: your last point is wrong. If the original body is now a teacup, you die because your body is now dead porcelain.

Comment: @DaleM I consider that a possibility.  However, a character that gets true polymorphed into a teacup is not considered dead, and ostensibly their soul is still there in the cup somehow, because a dispel magic ends the shape change, and the character would be right as they were prior to true polymorph with no concept of the time passed as a teacup.  What's described here is a way to be "out of your mind" so you can still concentrate and turn yourself into a teacup instead of having to bother one of your other archmage colleagues.

Comment: @DaleM Unless one is living porcelain, as in the Disney Animated film "Sleeping Beauty" :)  (Voiced by Angela Landsbury ...)

Comment: @KorvinStarmast Beauty and the Beast... :P